# How to conserve wastage of storage space in terms of # of blocks used when designing a file system

Tags: memory-management, filesystems, storage, block

As a part of my thesis, I'm working on designing a storage sub-system. I have to create an inode like structure (like ext3 indirect block usage etc.). On the same lines as ext3 but I have 2 different page/block sizes - 16k and 512k (for direct block accesses). I can have 36 blocks total. My question is how many blocks of each size should be used to minimize internal fragmentation or wasted storage space. Someone suggested keeping 32, 16k blocks since 16k * 32 = 512k and that would avoid space wastage but I didn't follow the argument much. Please help me understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

The question to ask first is: what is the average file size that you encounter? Lets say that the average file size is 256K...there can be file size more than 256K and less, but the average is 256K. If so, keeping one 512K block as the direct block causes internal fragmentation. Having 16K blocks as direct blocks covers all files sizes <= 512K. So, to reduce internal fragmentation, the better size would be 16K.

Now that you know this, there are two questions I will ask you:

- If you go back to the original Unix design, why was 8 direct block pointers used in the inode? Why are you trying to use 32?
- The second question to ask is: why does your storage system support 16K and 512K block sizes?

I will wait for your answer here :-)

Comment: Lets just assume, these are dummy values but the ratios stay (as I can't reveal much info) :(

Comment: So we're implementing a filesystem for High performance scientific applications and our inode can have references to 36 blocks in total. Average file size is > 512 k. Why these values, that is clear to me which unfortunately I can't share but how to split the 36 blocks to 32 and what other numbers is not.

Comment: If avg file size is >512K, what % of files are <512K? If only 1% of files fall below 512K, then I'd keep the 36 direct block as 512K blocks. Internal frag on 1% of files is a price to be paid for faster access for >512K sized files: if file size is less than 36*512K, then no need to go through indirect blocks which add an additional block read. If 20% of files fall below 512K, then I would have to allocate some 16K block to represent the smaller files. Say, of the 20%, 90% of the files are 16K. Then only 1 block pointer can be 16K and the rest of them can be 512K blk pointers.

Comment: In the suggestion you got, 32 16K block pointers => 4 512K blocks => 1MB of files can be accessed by direct block pointers. If 90% of files are 1MB or less, then the block pointers can be stored in the inode itself and no need to read additional indirects/double indirects/triple indirects, etc. But, if 90% of files are 10MB, then you can represent them with 20 512K block pointers but you would not be able to represent them within 36 block pointers space if you used 32 16K blocks + 4 512K blocks. So, it all depends on file size distributions that you are targeting the file system for.